# Python - match letters of words in a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a simple program where a user enters a few letters

Enter letters: abc

I then want to run through a list of words I have in list and match and words that contain 'a','b', and 'c'.

This is what I've tried so far with no luck

```
for word in good_words: #For all words in good words list
    for letter in letters: #for each letter inputed by user
        if not(letter in word):
            break
    matches.append(word)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want `all` the letters inside the word:

```
[word for word in good_words if all(letter in word for letter in letters)]
```

The problem with your code is the `break` inside the inner loop. Python doesn't have a construction to allow breaking more than one loop at once (and you wanted that)

Answer (score 2):

You could probably improve the spee using a [Set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) or FrozenSet

If you look at the doc, it mentionned the case of testing membership :

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects.
>   Common uses include **membership testing**, removing duplicates from a
>   sequence, and computing mathematical operations such as intersection,
>   union, difference, and symmetric difference.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions are definitely the way to go, but just to address the issue that OP was having with his code:

Your `break` statement only breaks out of the innermost loop. Because of that the word is still appended to `matches`. A quick fix for this is to take advantage of python's `for... else` construct:

```
for word in good_words:
    for letter in letters:
        if letter not in word:
            break
    else:
        matches.append(word)
```

In the above code, `else` only executes if the loop is allowed to run all the way through. The `break` statement exits out of the loop completely, and `matches.append(..)` is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections
```

I would first compute the occurrences of letters in the words list.

```
words_by_letters = collections.defaultdict(list)
for word in good_words:
    key = frozenset(word)
    words_by_letters[key].append(word)
```

Then it's simply a matter of looking for words with particular letter occurrences.  This is hopefully faster than checking each word individually.

```
subkey = set(letters)
for key, words in words_by_letters.iteritems():
    if key.issuperset(subkey):
        matches.extend(words)
```

If you want to keep track of letter repeats, you can do something similar by building a key from `collections.Counter`.

Comment: You should use `frozenset` because sets are not hashable